# When multiple biometric sensors are available, how to select preferred type to use?

Tags: android, biometrics

I am using [`BiometricPrompt`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/biometrics/BiometricPrompt) in this way:

```
val biometricPrompt = BiometricPrompt.Builder(this)
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", executor, cancelListener)
                    .build()

biometricPrompt.authenticate(
     getCancellationSignal(), 
     executor,
     getAuthenticationCallback())
```

A user reported that their phone has multiple biometric sensors available (fingerprint, iris and face) and that the app automatically selected iris with no option to choose another.  (In this case, the user preferred to use fingerprint.)  I don't see anything in the BiometricPrompt API that suggests you can select a default sensor type.

Is there a way to set a preferred biometric sensor type?

Comment: Can you at least reference what manufacturer/device. From what I could tell, Android 9 AOSP only has support for fingerprint: https://source.android.com/security/biometric

Comment: There's currently no way to do that, but I agree that there ought to be. I filed [an issue about that](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111315641) 6 months ago, but I haven't really heard anything back.